# javascript Solving equation with subsitution of variable value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the nerdamer library to solve equation. Following is example which works:
//multiple roots

```
var y = nerdamer.solve('x^6+41*x^5+652*x^4+5102*x^3+20581*x^2+40361*x+30030', 'x');
console.log(x4.toString());
```

But I want to solve with expression containing constant variable calculated already. For example:

```
var y= nerdamer.solve('x^6+a*x^5+652*x^4+b*x^3+20581*x^2+40361*x+30030', 'x');
```

where a and b have already been calculated in javascript code above this expression.

How can I do it? is it possible to convert terms into strings and concatenate?

thank you

Comment: since it is a string try template literals or just concatenate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, you could use string concatenation:

```js
var y= nerdamer.solve('x^6+' + a + '*x^5+652*x^4+' + b + '*x^3+20581*x^2+40361*x+30030', 'x');
```

Or [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to allow for variable substitution:

```js
var y= nerdamer.solve(`x^6+${a}*x^5+652*x^4+${b}*x^3+20581*x^2+40361*x+30030`, 'x');
```